# Combining several query results into one result

Tags: sql-server, database-design, union

I am using SQL Server. I have 5 tables (MTable, C1Table, C2Table, C3Table, C4Table).

In MTable I have 4 queries and each one of them gives correct result:

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
    MTable.cID, MTable.COL1, MTable.COL2, MTable.COL4, MTable.COL5, 
    MTable.COL6, MTable.Col7, MTable.Col8, MTable.Col9, MTable.Col10, 
    MTable.Col11, 
    C1Table.Col12, C1Table.Col13, C1Table.Col14, C1Table.Col15 
FROM 
    MTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    C1Table ON MTable.COL2 = C1Table.COL2 
WHERE 
    (MTable.COL6 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL5 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL4 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL2 > 0)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  
    MTable.cID, MTable.COL1, MTable.COL2, MTable.COL4, MTable.COL5, 
    MTable.COL6, MTable.Col7, MTable.Col8, MTable.Col9, MTable.Col10, 
    MTable.Col11, 
    C2Table.Col12, C2Table.Col13, C2Table.Col14, C2Table.Col15 
FROM 
    MTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    C2Table ON MTable.COL4 = C2Table.COL4 
WHERE 
    (MTable.COL6 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL5 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL4 > 0)
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT 
    MTable.cID, MTable.COL1, MTable.COL2, MTable.COL4, MTable.COL5, 
    MTable.COL6, MTable.Col7, MTable.Col8, MTable.Col9, MTable.Col10, 
    MTable.Col11, 
    C3Table.Col12, C3Table.Col13, C3Table.Col14, C3Table.Col15 
FROM 
    MTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    C3Table ON MTable.COL5 = C3Table.COL5 
WHERE 
    (MTable.COL6 = 0) 
    AND (MTable.COL5 > 0)
```

Query 4:

```
SELECT 
    MTable.cID, MTable.COL1, MTable.COL2, MTable.COL4, MTable.COL5, 
    MTable.COL6, MTable.Col7, MTable.Col8, MTable.Col9, MTable.Col10, 
    MTable.Col11, 
    C4Table.Col12, C4Table.Col13, C4Table.Col14, C4Table.Col15 
FROM 
    MTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    C4Table ON MTable.COL6 = C4Table.COL6 
WHERE 
    (MTable.COL6 > 0)
```

Now I should be able to create a query which combines those results into one. This is gives correct result as amount:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ThisCount) AS Expr1 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount 
     FROM MTable 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN C1Table ON MTable.COL1 = C1Table.COL1 
     WHERE (MTable.COL4 = 0) 
       AND (MTable.COL3 = 0) 
       AND (MTable.COL2 = 0) 
       AND (MTable.COL1 > 0) 

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount 
     FROM MTable AS MTable_3 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN C2Table ON MTable_3.COL2 = C2Table.COL2 
     WHERE (MTable_3.COL4 = 0) 
       AND (MTable_3.COL3 = 0) 
       AND (MTable_3.COL2 > 0) 

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount 
     FROM MTable AS MTable_2 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN C3Table ON MTable_2.COL3 = C3Table.COL3 
     WHERE (MTable_2.COL4 = 0) 
       AND (MTable_2.COL3 > 0) 

     UNION ALL 

     SELECT COUNT(*) AS ThisCount 
     FROM MTable AS MTable_1 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN C4Table ON MTable_1.COL4 = C4Table.COL4 
     WHERE (MTable_1.COL4 > 0) ) AS x
```

But I need to have a list of each result (now I should have result of about 3 000 rows).

I have tried "UNION ALL", but I am getting error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which error you face?

Comment: why don't you insert all the Result in a Temporary Table and fetch result from it

Comment: You should not have any problems with union all. Is it by any chance that your error is something like "not contained in an aggregate function" ?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

create temp table for each query and combine all the tables then on what column you need sum based on requirement

```
SELECT MTable.cID
    ,MTable.COL1
    ,MTable.COL2
    ,MTable.COL4
    ,MTable.COL5
    ,MTable.COL6
    ,MTable.Col7
    ,MTable.Col8
    ,MTable.Col9
    ,MTable.Col10
    ,MTable.Col11
    ,C1Table.Col12
    ,C1Table.Col13
    ,C1Table.Col14
    ,C1Table.Col15
    INTO #A
FROM MTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN C1Table ON MTable.COL2 = C1Table.COL2
WHERE (MTable.COL6 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL5 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL4 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL2 > 0)


    SELECT MTable.cID
    ,MTable.COL1
    ,MTable.COL2
    ,MTable.COL4
    ,MTable.COL5
    ,MTable.COL6
    ,MTable.Col7
    ,MTable.Col8
    ,MTable.Col9
    ,MTable.Col10
    ,MTable.Col11
    ,C2Table.Col12
    ,C2Table.Col13
    ,C2Table.Col14
    ,C2Table.Col15
        INTO #B
FROM MTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN C2Table ON MTable.COL4 = C2Table.COL4
WHERE (MTable.COL6 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL5 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL4 > 0)

    SELECT MTable.cID
    ,MTable.COL1
    ,MTable.COL2
    ,MTable.COL4
    ,MTable.COL5
    ,MTable.COL6
    ,MTable.Col7
    ,MTable.Col8
    ,MTable.Col9
    ,MTable.Col10
    ,MTable.Col11
    ,C3Table.Col12
    ,C3Table.Col13
    ,C3Table.Col14
    ,C3Table.Col15
            INTO #C
FROM MTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN C3Table ON MTable.COL5 = C3Table.COL5
WHERE (MTable.COL6 = 0)
    AND (MTable.COL5 > 0)
    SELECT MTable.cID
    ,MTable.COL1
    ,MTable.COL2
    ,MTable.COL4
    ,MTable.COL5
    ,MTable.COL6
    ,MTable.Col7
    ,MTable.Col8
    ,MTable.Col9
    ,MTable.Col10
    ,MTable.Col11
    ,C4Table.Col12
    ,C4Table.Col13
    ,C4Table.Col14
    ,C4Table.Col15
            INTO #D
FROM MTable
LEFT OUTER JOIN C4Table ON MTable.COL6 = C4Table.COL6
WHERE (MTable.COL6 > 0)


select sum(value) from (SELECT count(*) value FROM #A
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) value FROM #B
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) value FROM #C
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) value FROM #D) c
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I figured it out and it is "Query1" UNION ALL "Query2" UNION ALL "Query3" UNION ALL "Query4".